# Number of tablets per table in YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I have one question regarding the number of tablets for a table.
I am using YSQL API, my cluster is having 3 nodes with an RF of 3 and each node is having 16 cores.
I haven't specified the number of shards per table using `SPLIT INTO N TABLETS` syntax so I guess the number of tablets will be decided by the cores a node has, based on documentation it will be 8 shards per table per node.
In this case, the total shards for a table should be `24=(8 x 3)`
We have RF=3 as well, so will that mean the total shards after replication will be `72? (24 x 3)`
I am confused here, as I have seen only 24 shards in the tserver tablets UI where it's mentioned that 8 shards are the leaders out of 24. Seeing this it seems the 24 shards contain the replicated ones as well.

Please correct my understanding here. I am using YugabyteDB 2.12, latest stable

Output of - `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core id'`
[image]

This is for one table, at the left, it shows 24 shards, 8 are leaders and the rest are followers:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your numbers are correct. 24 tablets is `per tserver`, 72 is for the 3 node cluster. 8 leaders per tserver, 24 leaders for the 3 node cluster.

And your screenshots are from one tserver endpoint (:9000/tables) The master endpoint (localhost:7000/table?id=000030af000030008000000000004200) will show you all tablets and their peers